# Bit Crusher Plug for PT

Tags: plugin, design

PT's Lo-Fi Plugin is not adequate for me at the moment.  I'm looking to get some juicy bit crushed sounds and I come up a mile short.  The best bit-crush that I have heard of is on Traktor the DJing software.

What bit-crusher does bring the heat?  Any free RTAS?

Answer (score 1):

I loved pluggo's Degrader (cycling 74).. so crunchy..

Alas they've thrown it on the scrap-heap, and it only sort of works with PT now as it's not been supported from v.7 I think.

Depending on which version of Tools you're running it might work, but you'll have to be creative finding a copy because I don't think it's for sale. Worth it if you can get it though.

Answer (score 1):

**+decimate** by Tom Erbe is pretty rad: http://soundhack.henfast.com/freeware/